# Show gif animation while LinkedIn member profile is loading

Tags: animation, plugins, loading, linkedin-api

I wanted to show an animated gif while the LinkedIn Member Profile Plugin is being loaded.

Here is the original code:

```
<script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="http://www.linkedin.com/in/reidhoffman"
data-format="inline"></script>
```

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494965/show-loading-gif-before-starting-script) but I'm not sure how I can apply that to the LinkedIn script.

Any solutions would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure something using related [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769892/how-to-show-loading-gif-image-while-content-called-via-javascript-is-loading) but the gif gets removed few seconds before the script is actually displayed.

I placed the linkedin plugin codes in linkedin.js and tried both below methods:

1:

```
$('#linkedin').html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />').load("linkedin.js");
```

2:

```
$('#linkedin').append('<img id="animation" src="ajax-loader.gif" />')
      .load("linkedin.js")
              .complete(function(data) { $('#animation').remove(); });
```

HTML

```
<div id="linkedin"></div>
```

I suppose the gif is removed once the script is loaded and yet to be executed? I also tried using getScript() couldn't get any results.